# Add active class to menu item when page was not in URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I have a web application build with ASP.NET webform that uses Javascript to make the selected item active in the menu.

To obtain this result, the system compares the URL visited and the one present in the URL of the selected menu. If they match, the ACTIVE class is added.

```
// activate the menu in left side bar based on url
    $("#side-menu a").each(function () {
        var pageUrl = window.location.href.split(/[?#]/)[0];
        if (this.href == pageUrl) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active"); // add active to li of the current link
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("in");
            $(this).parent().parent().prev().addClass("active"); // add active class to an anchor
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("active");
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("in"); // add active to li of the current link
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

My problem is that the visited page is not always present in the menu. For example: I have a page (Product list) in the menu. When selected this item ACTIVE  class was added.

If I need more details on a product, I click on the list to view the page with the details. This page was not in menu so no menu item was active.

How can I solve?

Is there a way to leave the previous active menu item selected?

Comment: Why don't you use [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8) to store the active menu item?

Comment: And how can read Session variable in javascript?

Comment: You can read with `'<%= Session["VariableName"].ToString() %>'`.